# How can I compile the pdf!

Tags: pdf, compiling

How everyone, please I don't know where is the problem but I cannot compile the pdf

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[arabic,french,farsi]{babel}
\newcommand*\varhrulefill[1][0.4pt]{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height#1\hfill\kern0pt}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{frcursive}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\linespread{1.3}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}

\begin{document}

\newpage % بداية صفحة التلاخيص
\thispagestyle{empty}  %لازالة رقم الصفحة

\vspace{1cm} %ترك مسافة قبل التلاخيص في أعلى الصفحة
\selectlanguage{french} %إختيار اللغة الفرنسية
\begin{center}\[\mathpzc{\textbf{\textit{\LARGE Abstract}}}\]  \end{center}
  \par \textbf{In this work, we have focused on the planar polynomial systems and studied the Hopf bifurcations and bifurcations of limit cycles from a multiple focus and bifurcations at non-hyperbolic equilibrium point where limit cycles can be made to bifurcate. In particular, the limit cycles and global phase portrait of class of rigid systems under its parameters. The results of bifurcations of limit cycles are proved by the uses of the Poincaré map and drawing all diffrent phase portraits. \\
\textbf{\large\textit{Key words:}} Hopf bifurcation, Poincar\'{e} map, phase portrait, rigid system, limit cycle, non-hyperbolic.}

\vspace{1cm}  % جعل مسافة بين الملخص الأول و الثاني
\selectlanguage{farsi} %إختيار اللغة العربية
\noindent\varhrulefill
\vspace{1cm}  
\begin{center} {\LARGE ملخص }   \end{center}
\par
في هذا العمل ، ركزنا على الأنظمة المستوية  متعددة الحدود ودرسنا تشعبات هوبف والتشعبات للحلول الدورية المعزولة من نقاط التركيز و التشعبات عند نقطة التوازن غير القطعي حيث يمكن نشاة الحلول الدورية المعزولة. على وجه الخصوص ، الحلول الدورية المعزولة  والرسم الكلي لفئة الأنظمة الصلبة تحت تاثير متغيراتها.
النتائج المستخرجة من دراسة الحلول الدورية المعزولة  مبرهنة باستخدام ماب بوانكاري ورسم الحلول.
\\
\par الكلمات المفتاحية: تشعب هوبف ،ماب  بوانكاريه ، رسم الحلول ، الانظمة الصلبة ، دورة حد ، نقطة توازن غير زائدي.

\vspace{1cm}    % جعل مسافة بين الملخص الثاني و الثالث
\selectlanguage{french} %إختيار الفرنسية لكتابة الإنجليزية
\noindent\varhrulefill
\vspace{1cm}  
\begin{center}\begin{cursive} \textbf{\textit{\LARGE Résumé}}\end{cursive} \end{center}
  \par \textbf{Dans ce travail, nous sommes concentrés sur les systèmes polynomiaux planaires et nous sommes  étudié les bifurcations  de Hopf et les bifurcations des  cycles limites à partir d'un foyer multiple,  et des bifurcations au point d'équilibre non hyperbolique où les cycles limites peuvent cree.  En particulier, les cycles limites et le portrait de phase global de la classe des systèmes rigides sous ses paramètres. Les résultats des bifurcations de cycles limites sont prouvés par les utilisations de la carte de Poincaré et par le dessin de tous différents les portraits de phase . \\
\textbf{\large\textit{Mots clés:}} Bifurcation de Hopf, carte de Poincar\'{e} , 
portrait de phase, system rigide, cycle limite, 
non hyperbolique. }

\newpage  %للخروج من صفحة التلاخيص و الكتابة في الصفحة الموالية
%\selectlanguage{arabic} %الرجوع إلى اللغة العربية إذا كانت هى الأصلية
%\selectlanguage{french} %الرجوع إلى اللغة الفرنسية إذا كانت هى الأصلية
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I have no problem compiling the document using either pdfLaTeX or XeLaTeX. Can you provide details into what is "cannot compile"?

Comment: Off-topic: `\[\mathpzc{\textbf{\textit{\LARGE Abstract}}}\]` could (should?) be simplified to `\textbf{\textit{\LARGE Abstract}}`.

Comment: When compile fails, there will be one or more messages in the log file. This tells you what happened. Sometimes tghe message is hard to understand. But if you copy the last few lines of the log file, and post it here, then somebody may be able to understand it. Also: What is your compiler? What operating system?